# Spring file integration java config

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I want to use Spring integration to develop an application to do following

1. Poll the file in a directory when its available.
2. Copy the file to archive directory
3. process the file and add the path to the database.

I am not sure how to configure this and i dont find any good documentation. Most of them are configuration in xml and i want java config.
I have this code but this is just copying the file and delete the source. i dont know how to process the source.

```
 @Bean
    public MessageChannel fileInputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }
    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "fileInputChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000"))
    public MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageSource() {
        FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
        source.setDirectory(new File(INBOUND_PATH));
        source.setFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter("*.pdf"));

        source.setLoggingEnabled(true);
        return source;
    }


    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fileInputChannel")
    public FileWritingMessageHandler fileWritingMessageHandler() {


        FileWritingMessageHandler fileWritingMessageHandler = new FileWritingMessageHandler(
                new File(OUTBOUND_PATH));
        fileWritingMessageHandler.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
        fileWritingMessageHandler.setExpectReply(false);
        fileWritingMessageHandler.setDeleteSourceFiles(true);
        return fileWritingMessageHandler;
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at SI samples - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples? I mean there are plenty of docs and samples. In the provided link you can find all samples categorised from simple individual components to sample apps that constitute the entire flow. For example, the https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/applications/file-split-ftp is very close to your use case.

Answer (score 2):

You have a specific business requirements and even if we have samples in Java that doesn't mean your use-case is going to be covered there. We are fully open for contribution into samples project Oleg mentions in his comments, but that's already up to you, Community. We here really can't guess all the field use-case to cover in the sample.

Some solution for your request could be like this:

1. The `fileInputChannel` has to be a `PublishSubscribeChannel` with your existing `fileWritingMessageHandler()` as a *second* subscriber.
2. You add a first subscriber (`@ServiceActivator`) to process that file and as you said store in DB, which definitely could be as the next `@ServiceActivator` after this one.

See `@Order` annotation to be present alongside with the mentioned `@ServiceActivator` to be sure that your subscribers are subscribed in the proper order. Since you really going to move the file, it is very important to process it before sending to that `FileWritingMessageHandler`.

This task also could be done using Java DSL and even probably its code could be much shorter.

Saying that I would ask you to read documentation starting with [EIP Book](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/) to make yourself familiar with integration concepts and principles.